# Interactive CSS boxes depending on browser/screen size

Tags: html, css, size, interactive

01) I am trying to create a row with two content boxes. The first one will contain an image and the second one text. I am having a problem on how to make it interactive depending on the browser and screen size.

So, I want to have this result and I want it to be responsive/interactive depending on the screen size:

[image]

It is the reason why I added : `<div class="inner"></div>` trying to control the max dimensions but it did not work.

**HTML**:

```
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rich_text.css">
</head>

<div class="inner">
    <div class="feature left">
        <span class="image"><img src="http://SITE.co.uk/images/bg3.png" alt="" />

        </span>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Total Facebook Image Likes</h2>
            <p>65 </p>
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><a class="button alt" href="#">LINK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:
[CSS LINK](http://SITE.co.uk/rich_text.css)

02) I also noticed that my final results gets spoiled if the image size is too big.

I tried adding that :

```
<span class="image"><img style="height:400px;max-width:400px; src="http://SITE.co.uk/images/bg3.png" alt="" />
```

But the image does not load.

Comment: For problem 2: It seems you forgot to close the style tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have elements responsive and change based on screen width then you can use percent or viewport units (`%`, `vh` and `vw`).

Consider the following code:

```css
/* demo purpose only */
.row { margin-bottom:1em;}
.red {background:red;}
.blue {background:blue;}

/* make all divs inside a row get 50% width */
.row div {
  width:50%;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* this makes sure paddings or borders don't break width calculation */
  padding: 1em;
  color:#FFF;
}

/* by default, all divs have auto width, usually covering 100% of their parent tag */
.row.default div { width: auto; }

/* floating divs to the left will make them next to each other instead of under each other */
.row.floated div { float:left; }

/* adding overflow:auto to the parent of flaoted divs will make sure the layout does not break */
.row.floated { overflow:auto; }

/* rows can have any width you want, the children will resize accordingly and will always be 50% of whatever width the parent has */
.row.maxwidth {max-width:400px;}

/* we can make the children as inline-blocks instead of floating */
/* warning: space in HTML code between inline-blocks will break the layout so be careful */
.row.inline div {display:inline-block;}

/* we can use viewport untis */
/* vw = viewport width */
/* vh = viewport height */
/* 50vw = 50% of viewport width */
.row.vw div { width: 50vw; }
```

```html
<h2>1. Default Behaviour</h2>
<div class="row default">
  <div class="red">default block</div>
  <div class="blue">default block</div>
</div>

<h2>2. Percentage Width (based on parent)</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="red">50% width block</div>
  <div class="blue">50% width block</div>
</div>

<h2>3.1 Percentage Width + Floating</h2>
<div class="row floated">
  <div class="red">50% width block - floated</div>
  <div class="blue">50% width block - floated </div>
</div>

<h2>3.2 Parent with max-width of 400px</h2>
<div class="row floated maxwidth">
  <div class="red">50% width block - floated</div>
  <div class="blue">50% width block - floated </div>
</div>

<h2>4. Percentage Width + Inline-block</h2>
<div class="row inline">
  <div class="red">50% width inline-block</div><div class="blue">50% width inline-block</div>
</div>

<h2>5. Viewport Width (based on viewport)</h2>
<div class="row vw floated">
  <div class="red">50vw width block - floated</div>
  <div class="blue">50vw width block - floated</div>
</div>
```

The code is pretty commented to help you understand how everything works and some various methods of achieving what you want. I would just recommend using percentage widths and floating them. Alternatively, you could use powerful grid systems like Bootstrap which already has a library of 12-column grid that you can use without having to write a custom layout grid base.

Comment: Great answer. I thought it was the solution itself in the beginning. It is a perfect tutorial to help me do it. Cheers